# How to deny from domain but allow ip from that domain in apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I am updating a .htaccess file to use apache 2.4  directives instead of the previous allow/deny syntax.
I am trying to deny access from amazonaws.com because it is mostly automated traffic/bots. I realized that slackbot uses aws for social media previews which do not work when denying host. Is there a way to block amazonaws but allow specific ip or user agent from amazonaws domain? Something like the following perhaps? I know that won't work but am seeking something like it that does.

```
<RequireAll> 
Require all granted
  Require not host amazonaws.com
  Require ip (ip from amazonaws.com)
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: Why do you insist on using RequireAll? It seems like an arbitrary requirement.

Comment: Only because allow/deny is deprecated. But I'm open to any solution.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Yes, that describes your concern much more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The condition "block amazonaws but allow specific ip" means that *one* of the two conditions "not amazonaws" or "specific ip" must be fulfilled in order to allow access. So you need to use the `<RequireAny>` directive to join those two conditions, like this:

```
<RequireAny>
Require not host amazonaws.com
Require ip (ip from amazonaws.com)
</RequireAny>
```

Omit the `Require all granted` directive. It would grant access unconditionally to everybody which is not what you want.

Comment: Not working. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Qualify "not working". Check for typos. Inspect the Apache log.

Comment: The require ip is not overruling require not host rule.

Comment: It should. You'll have to troubleshoot why it doesn't in your case. As I wrote, check for typos and inspect the Apache log for clues.

Comment: I'd say requireall tag with the same Require specified here, an example of accesses would be better though.

Comment: I don't believe I have access to Apache log on the shared server.